# Problema em consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com um problema numa consulta MySQL.
Nela tenho 3 tabelas que preciso cruzar:

Tabela "desenho":

```
id
concurso_id
customer_id
```

Tabela "concurso":

```
id 
titulo   
criterioDiasCorridos
criterioNotaMedia
criterioMinimoVotos
```

Tabela "notadesenho":

```
customer_id
desenho_id
concurso_id
nota
```

Trata-se de um sistema de votação onde preciso listar todos os DESENHOS do CONCURSO X (concurso.id = X) e SOMAR quantidade de votos que o desenho teve (notadesenho.desenho_id) e exibir a MÉDIA de votos também (notadesenho.nota).

Fiz a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.nome,
    d.descricao,
    d.arquivo,
    d.tags,
    d.concurso_id,
    c.criterioNotaMedia,
    c.criterioMinimoVotos,
    c.criterioDiasCorridos,
    COUNT(n.desenho_id) as quantidadeVotos,
    IFNULL(AVG(n.nota), 0) as notaDesenho
FROM desenho d
LEFT JOIN concurso c ON d.concurso_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN notadesenho n ON d.id = n.desenho_id
WHERE c.id = $idConcurso
```

Mas ele está retornando apenas 1 desenho quando peço para listar todos a partir do concurso X.

Suspeito que o problema esteja nas ligações JOIN. Mas não estou conseguindo visualizar a solução.

Comment: Felipe, se puder, crie um [MCVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) com seu schema e uma amostra dos dados em uma ferramenta de depuração de SQL Online (p.e: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)). Torna mais fácil a visualização do problema e a descoberta da solução.

Comment: Para mim está claro o suficiente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema em sua query está no `COUNT()` e no `AVG()`.

Elas são funções agregadas e devem ser utilizadas juntamente com `GROUP BY` para produzir o resultado esperado.

Sua query deve ficar com algo parecido com isso (Agrupando os desenhos pelo id):

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.nome,
    d.descricao,
    d.arquivo,
    d.tags,
    d.concurso_id,
    c.criterioNotaMedia,
    c.criterioMinimoVotos,
    c.criterioDiasCorridos,
    COUNT(n.desenho_id) as quantidadeVotos,
    IFNULL(AVG(n.nota), 0) as notaDesenho
FROM desenho d
LEFT JOIN concurso c ON d.concurso_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN notadesenho n ON d.id = n.desenho_id
WHERE c.id = $idConcurso
GROUP BY d.id
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: apenas uma dúvida, existe uma ordem para colocar o "Group by" na query toda? Ela obrigatoriamente precisa ir embaixo de tudo? Pois minha dúvida é:
Posso usar Group By e Order By com o mesmo campo?

     GROUP BY d.id
     ORDER BY d.id $order

Comment: @Felipe `order by` sempre no final da query. Para entender um pouco sobre como as querys são executadas, veja essa resposta (em inglês) : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72022/mysql-select-using-alias/72023#72023